# Refresh tag value with dynamically generated data

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a main php page displaying dynamically generated cards through a loop. I am trying to refresh the content for certain tags, but it doesn't seem to work so far.

This is my main.php file:

```
<div class="col" style="width: ">
   <div class="card shadow-sm h-100 border-dark rounded" style="width: 240px; background-color: #ededed">
       <span class="mySpan">
           <div class="container">
               <input type="hidden" class="cardid" name="mycardId" value="
                <?php echo $cardId ?>" id="cardid">
               <div class="card-body px-0 py-0">
                   <table id="firstTable" class="table table-responsive-md table-striped table-borderless text-center mb-0" style="width: 237px; table-layout: fixed;">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th colspan="3" id="row1field1" name="row1field1" class="text-center py-1 px-1 fw-bold 
                                    <?php if($selectField == "EXP") echo "text-decoration-line-through" ?>" style="max-width: 237px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 18px;" contenteditable="true" data-name="row1field1"> <?php echo $row1field1; ?> </th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                   </table>

                   <table id="row4" class="table table-responsive-md table-striped table-borderless text-center mb-0" style="max-width: 238px; min-height: 50px; border: thin solid lightgray">
                       <tr>
                           <td name="row4field1" id="row4field1" class=" py-1" style="max-width: 104px; border-right: thin solid gray; text-transform: uppercase;" contenteditable="true">
                               <h6>
                                   <strong> <?php echo $row4field1; ?> </strong>
                               </h6>
                           </td>
                           <td name="row4field2" id="row4field2" class=" py-1" style="max-width: 104px; text-transform: uppercase;" contenteditable="true">
                               <h6>
                                   <strong> <?php echo $row4field2; ?> </strong>
                               </h6>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
               </div>
           <div>
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried so far using javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#row1field1").load(" #row1field1 > *");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Unfortunately, after the refresh, all content from row1field1 is gone. I believe this could be because the IDs are not unique, but I'm using the hidden value cardId to differentiate each card. Any advice on how to properly refresh these dynamic content is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique! The format you have used in the jQuery code is, er, unusual - should that not be `$('#row1field1')` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Professor Abronsius. I fixed my code but it is still not refreshing the content as expected.

Comment: You may need to wrap the content of row1field1 in a span or something (and then, you can say load(" row1field1 > span")).